# Sorting SQL query in RAND with exceptions

Tags: html, sql

I have a table with 21 rows I want row 10 20 and 21 to be row 10 20 and 21 on an html table using the query though I would like 1-9 and 11-19 to be random of the other rows. I can not find anything on how to put in exceptions for the random sorting. Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such as row 10 or 20 or 21.

Comment: ok I understand what you are saying I am stating as if you had a id column with ids 1-21 I want to order the rows by the id in random or except id 10 20 and 21 need to be on rows 10 20 and 21 is there a way to do this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unless you use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function :)

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to number your rows in the order you want, e.g. by ID. Then in your `ORDER BY` clause order the blocks first (rows 1-9, 10, 11-19, 20, 21), then shuffle inside the blocks using a random function.

The following is MySQL. It supports `ROW_NUMBER()` as of version 8. Its random function is called `RAND()`. Other DBMS may have another function to get a random number.

```
select t.*, 
from mytable
order by 
  case
    when row_number() over (order by id) <= 9 then 1
    when row_number() over (order by id) = 10 then 2
    when row_number() over (order by id) < 20 then 3
    when row_number() over (order by id) = 20 then 4
    when row_number() over (order by id) = 21 then 5
    else 6
  end,
  rand();
```